# Swagger Specification file for SurveyMonkey API

Tags: rest, swagger, openapi, surveymonkey

I'm currently working on developing connector for the surveymonkey Rest API. Is there any OpenAPI Specification file for the same that has all the endpoints as per the [docs](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/)? If not, can I get it in the near future?

Answer (score 1):

In researching the same question, I discovered that you can export the Survey Monkey collection from Postman as a JSON file, then convert it to OpenAPI format using this tool: https://kevinswiber.github.io/postman2openapi/.

Postman is working on a new feature to make this functionality available directly within their tool as well.